# QUERY not pulling numerical value into new tab

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull complete rows from column C of the parent tab by a specific number.

Right now, the =query is just pulling the headers.

```
=query('PARENT'!1:100000000, "Select * Where C = '1311'",1)
```

ex.  I want the new tab to pull all entries that match '1311' in column C of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=QUERY(PARENT!1:1000, "where C matches '1311'", 1)
```

Comment: =QUERY('PARENT'!1:1000, "where C matches '1311'", 1)

Works with the apostrophe added back in!